How identity and access control concepts apply in .NET Framework windows authentication, identity framework and membership provider
Many questions after learning basic concepts about .NET Framework identity and access control. The material was from before identity framework was introduced.
I am having a hard time putting it all together.
Here's what I learned about:
Principals, claims, identity class, how to branch code or restrict functions based on claims or roles (principalpermission), etc, how to setup principals, use principals (for forms and windows authentication). <= .NET Framework 4.8
also know somewhat about the request pipeline and how windows principal is set
Now how do all of these concepts apply to identity framework? I have also heard about a membership provider from before aspnet, I haven't learned about membership provider. How do the concepts I learnt relate to it? I will use ASP.NET MVC, Webforms, and windows forms.
Most applications I will work with are intranet applications, so I need windows authentication. Does aspnet identity or membership provider have anything to do with windows authentication?
Given a database with a table with usernames (unique to windows user) and roles, how can authorization be done with windows authentication? Do I simply branch after a database query to get the roles from db related to current principal?
Is there a good indepth tutorial or demo application which uses windows authentication? (Winforms, mvc5, webforms)
I have tried searching through the web for how these ideas are connected. Everything I could find is focused on one thing like Identity framework, or windows authentication.
I have tried WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().IsInRole() to branch code. Are there better ways?
